# Copy/paste Data from 1 sheet to another by matching specific cell or data (Date)

Tags: c#, excel

I have two sheets in Excel. Sheet2 contains data and I need that is on per date for 1 month, I would like to copy/paste the data on sheet1 by matching the date I put on the Blank date, example: Put Oct 1 on the date of sheet1 it will automatically copy the data of Oct 1 on sheet2. put Oct 2 copy data on Oct 2 an so on..

SHEET 1

```
DATE            
Turnover  IN     out    Revenue
0     0  0   0
0     0  0   0
0     0  0   0
0     0  0   0
0     0  0   0
0     0  0   0
0     0  0   0
0     0  0   0
```

SHEET 2

```
1-Oct                           2-Oct           
Turnover IN  OUT     RESULT     Turnover IN  OUT     RESULT
14599    4410    4500    -90        1000     54641   737542  -90
67530    9330    1440    7890       100  345     4274    7890
57699    11520   2673    8846       500  4525    275274  8846.5
196425   55960   68800   -12840     60050    42  4247    -12840
92100    17770   2500    15270      136450   4   14  15270
```

Answer (score 2):

well, to copy certain range(with cell content, ...) you should try following, for example:

```
 Excel.Range selCell1 = ((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet).Range["A1", "CA2000"];
 Excel.Range selCell2 = ((Excel.Worksheet)Application.Sheets[2]).Range["A1", "CA2000"];
 selCell1.Copy(selCell2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a C# solution? Otherwise you can easily construct this type of thing directly in the excel spreadsheet:

```
=INDEX($11:$20,ROW(),MATCH($A$1,$11:$11,0)+COLUMN()-1)
```

[image: IndexMatchExample]

Good Luck.